Calcite's planner produces incorrect CASE statement in WHERE filter that references computed field
I'm seeing what appears to be a bug when translating a logical plan to a physical plan when a computed column that uses a CASE statement is referenced in a WHERE clause.  The generated physical SQL is invalid, as it appears to be trying to coerce a CASE expression into a BOOLEAN.  It's unclear to me if I'm setting this up incorrectly or if this is a problem in the planner logic itself.
The following selects from a TEST relation with 2 columns and computes a 3rd using a CASE:
RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(config);

builder.scan("TEST"));
builder.project(builder.fields(List.of("TYPE","VALUE")));

// CASE WHEN TYPE = 'TEST_TYPE' THEN ABS(VALUE)
RexNode when = builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.EQUALS,
        builder.field("TYPE"),
        builder.literal("TEST_TYPE"));
RexNode then = builder.call(SqlStdOperatorTable.ABS,
        builder.field("VALUE"));

List<RexNode> whenArguments = new ArrayList<>();
whenArguments.add(when);
whenArguments.add(then);

// ELSE NULL END
RexNode elseCase = builder.getRexBuilder().makeNullLiteral(builder.getTypeFactory().createSqlType(SqlTypeName.FLOAT));
whenArguments.add(elseCase);

RexNode caseNode = builder.getRexBuilder().makeCall(SqlStdOperatorTable.CASE, whenArguments);

RelNode relNode = builder
        .projectPlus(builder.alias(caseNode, "ABSVAL"))  // Computed "ABSVAL"
        .filter(builder.greaterThan(caseNode, builder.literal(0))) // Effectively, ABSVAL > 0
        .build();

Translating this logical plan directly results in the SQL expected. A computed column cannot be referenced in the WHERE clause so the CASE is effectively repeated:
 SELECT TYPE,VALUE, 
        CASE WHEN TYPE = 'TEST_TYPE' THEN ABS( VALUE ) ELSE NULL END AS ABSVAL
   FROM TEST 
  WHERE CASE WHEN TYPE = 'TEST_TYPE' THEN ABS( VALUE ) ELSE NULL END > 0

However, when generating a physical plan from the logical plan, it seems want to translate the final NULL into a BOOLEAN expression which results in invalid SQL:
 SELECT TYPE,VALUE, 
        CASE WHEN TYPE = 'TEST_TYPE' THEN ABS( VALUE ) ELSE NULL END AS ABSVAL
   FROM TEST 
  WHERE CASE WHEN TYPE = 'TEST_TYPE' THEN ABS( VALUE ) > 0 ELSE FALSE END

The physical plan was computed via:
RelOptPlanner planner = relNode.getCluster().getPlanner();
RelOptUtil.registerDefaultRules(planner, false, false);
planner.setExecutor(new RexExecutorImpl(DataContexts.EMPTY));

final Program program = Programs.standard();
RelTraitSet desiredTraits = relNode.getTraitSet()
                .replace(EnumerableConvention.INSTANCE)
                .replace(RelCollations.EMPTY)
                .simplify();
RelNode physical = program.run(planner, relNode, desiredTraits, List.of(), List.of());

Map<String,Object> parameters = Map.of("_conformance", SqlConformanceEnum.DEFAULT);
EnumerableRelImplementor relImplementor =
    new EnumerableRelImplementor(physical.getCluster().getRexBuilder(), parameters);

final ClassDeclaration expr = relImplementor.implementRoot((EnumerableRel) physical, EnumerableRel.Prefer.ARRAY);
String s = Expressions.toString(expr.memberDeclarations, "\n", false);

The resultant physical SQL above is embedded in the final String
